# Kernel LDA in Julia. (trouble in package installing)

Tags: julia

I want to use Kernel LDA in julia 1.6.1.
I found the repo.
https://github.com/remusao/LDA.jl

I read READEME.md, and I typed

```
] add LDA
```

. But it does not work.

> The following package names could not be resolved:
> LDA (not found in project, manifest or registry

Also, I tried all of the following commands, still does not work.

```
add https://github.com/remusao/LDA.jl
add https://github.com/remusao/LDA.jl.git
Pkg.clone("https://github.com/remusao/LDA.jl.git")
```

What is the problem? How can I install LDA.jl in my julia?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The package you have linked, https://github.com/remusao/LDA.jl, has had no commits in over eight years. Among other things, it lacks a Project.toml file, which is necessary for installation in modern Julia.

Since Julia was only about one year old and at version 0.2 back in 2013 when this package last saw maintenance, the language has also changed drastically in this time such that the code in this package would likely no longer function even if you could get it to install.

If you can't find any alternative to this package for your work, forking it and upgrading it to work with modern Julia would be a nice intermediate-beginner project.

Comment: Oh, my, god... we cannot use Kernel LDA in julia easily. Soo sad. I will use python, thank you.

Comment: You asked about a particular *package* called LDA, which has been abandoned. If you asked about the *method*, people might know of other packages. Like https://multivariatestatsjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lda.html maybe, from 1 minue of searching?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. What I need is **Kernel** LDA. Unfortunately, your suggestion is non-kernel LDA. I could not find an available package of Kernel LDA from 1 minute of searching.

Comment: Ok. Others may know about these methods, if they are common then surely there is something newer. https://discourse.julialang.org may get more eyes. Updating LDA.jl would also be pretty simple (amazingly little has changed, for simple code like this) but it's certainly not well-tested, you'd still have to check carefully that it's working.